# Publishing Docker by proxing with NGINX, how to change port?

Tags: nginx, docker, port

I need to create a sevice at *port 12345*, but [the instructions](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#easy-start--docker) say

`docker run -p 80:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

... Can I change the *host port* (the final publishing is it?), **from 80 to 12345?**  Change  the *host port* or the *container port*?

So, I will use  `docker run -p 12345:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-ui`... It will work fine?

---

"Fine", for me: must work in an API Gateway (reverse proxy) at NGINX, as this script:

```
server {
        server_name api-guide.example.org;

        root /var/www/teste;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy {
                try_files $uri =404; 
                rewrite  ^/etc$   /$1   break;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345;
        }
}
```

proxing to the port 12345.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, **was my first *Docker***... It is running fine with `http://localhost:12345`!

So,  to map host's port 12345 to the container's port 8080, run `docker run -p 12345:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-ui &`, as I mentioned above... And use `docker ps` and `docker stop` to stop the service.

---

Tutorial, see https://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/